# KnockoutJs Checkbox Binding

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have been stuck for a couple days now and I have tried a few things in regards to pre-populating my checkbox. I have a view model and 2 functions called "callServiceget" which calls a webservice to get the value of my checkbox field (true or false) and "retVendor" which updates the value of the checkbox.

if the value of the checkbox in the database is true, I want it to be checked when i load the page, unfortunately, I am unable to accomplish this. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    <input class="input" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: vendor_inventory" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function VendorViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.vendor_inventory = ko.observable("");

        self.callServiceGet = function (id) {
                vendors.get("accounting", 2, id, self.retVendor);
        }

        self.retVendor = function (results) {
            self.vendor_inventory(results.inventory);
        }


        //self.vendor_inventory.subscribe(function (value) {
        //    alert(value);
        //},self);

    }
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 122;
    vm = new VendorViewModel();
    vm.callServiceGet(id);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Comment: what makes this line of code, explain parameters meaning vendors.get("accounting", 2, id, self.retVendor);

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly where your problem may be coming from, but the first thing that concerns me is that you call applyBindings() twice. You should call this one time and then update the model instead. That might be at least part of the problem.

Comment: vendors is a webservice and get is a function in the vendors webservice. It basically gets the value of the checkbox from the database based on the parameters i send as mentioned above. Will be either true or false which is what I get in self.retvendor.

Comment: What is wrong here? have you tried to debug and step through the server code to make sure something is returned? You can also step through client side code to make sure returned value is what you want.

Comment: Hi Ray, Server side code is perfect it returns me all the correct values. If i alert(self.vendor_inventory()); in self.retvendor it returns me a true which is correct.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79nhy/). I'll have to second @AdrienDelessert's comment, you'll need to track down the offending code and provide that as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am going to look into the server code again, just to make sure.

Comment: I dont seem to understand what the problem is considering im getting a true in my retVendor but my view refuses to get updated. What is even strange is the fact that even when i explicitly mention    self.vendor_inventory(true) in retVendor it does not get updated.

Comment: Hi. try to identify the type for `results.inventory`. If its not a proper javascript boolean that could be a problem. Basically a `typeof(results.inventory)` should return the value `boolean`